# What would be the idiomatic way of tracking ownership between a factory and its products?

Tags: rust, factory

I have a class that creates instances of another class. Occasionally it needs to react to or otherwise work with its products. However, it could create trouble if it were to be passed a product that it doesn't own. I have the following solution:

```
struct Parent {
    id: Option<*const Parent>,
    name: String,
}
impl Parent {
    fn new(name: String) -> Parent {
        Parent {
            id : None,
            name : name,
        }
    }
    fn spawn(&mut self, name: String) -> Child {
        if let None = self.id {
            self.id = Some(self as *const Parent);
        }
        Child {
            parent: self.id.unwrap(),
            name,
        }
    }
    fn is_parent(&self, child: &Child) -> bool {
        if self.id.unwrap() == child.parent {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
struct Child {
    parent: *const Parent,
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent_one = Parent::new(String::from("Bob"));
    let mut parent_two = Parent::new(String::from("Ben"));
    let child_one = parent_one.spawn(String::from("Barry"));
    let child_two = parent_two.spawn(String::from("Bishop"));
    if parent_one.is_parent(&child_one) {
        println!("{} is the parent of {}.",parent_one.name,child_one.name);
    }
    if parent_one.is_parent(&child_two) {
        println!("{} is the parent of {}.",parent_one.name,child_two.name);
    }   
    if parent_two.is_parent(&child_one) {
        println!("{} is the parent of {}.",parent_two.name,child_one.name);
    }
    if parent_two.is_parent(&child_two) {
        println!("{} is the parent of {}.",parent_two.name,child_two.name);
    }   
}
```

The first thing I fear is a parent being destroyed and the address being reused. Perhaps a time-stamp is required to further ensure ownership?

Even further, I wonder if Rust has a better way to handle this situation?

Edit:

This is just a minimal example. The complete code is a linked list library. Currently I am working on creating a function that allows removing a node from the list. This is done by calling on `List.remove(Node)`. But, I need to ensure that the node does belong to the provided List. Because, if you remove a head, a tail, or the final element, the List must be updated. If you provide a mismatch of List and Node the end result would be incorrect.

Edit 2:

I have confirmed that reusing the memory address is certainly a problem. Also while a time-stamp is helpful, without randomization, I fear it still isn't enough.

Comment: If you're just comparing the parent pointer as a unique identifier, why not just assign each parent an incrementing integer ID and have the child remember the ID of its parent?

Comment: This is just a minimal example. The complete code is a linked list library. I will submit an edit.

Comment: Yes there must be a better way to do this. Doing the check at compile time would be the best.

Comment: I can't even begin to think of how it could be done at compile-time. I know in C++ I could simply have a static variable that increases as an ID. But, I am avoiding use of externals libraries and unsafe code.

Comment: Use a reference-counted pointer. `Rc` and `Arc` have their own `Weak` references that may be used from a child to point to its parent. You might want to change your function to only accept a `Rc`/`Arc` wrapped `self`.

Comment: Using a pointer as an ID is simply a big no no (in any language) since it is not unique over time. It is an anti pattern. Don’t do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to take the 'globally incremented ID' approach, what you want is an `Id` type with an interface like this that you can store in your `Parent` and `Child` types:

```
pub struct Id(...);

impl Id {
   pub fn new() -> Id { ... }
}

impl PartialEq<Id> for Id {
   fn eq(&self, other: &Id) -> bool { ... }
}

impl Eq for Id { }
impl Clone for Id { fn clone(&self) -> Id { ... } }
```

There are a few ways to implement such a type, depending on your needs. If you never need to move or share a `Parent` or `Child` between threads, you can use a simple thread-local counter:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Id(u64, PhantomData<*mut ()>);

impl Id {
   pub fn new() -> Id {
       thread_local! (static NEXT_ID: Cell<u64> = Cell::new(0));
       let id = NEXT_ID.with(|cell| {
          let id = cell.get();
          cell.set(id.checked_add(1).expect("Ran out of IDs!"));
          id
       });
       Id(id, PhantomData)
   }
}
```

The only subtlety to this solution is the `PhantomData<*mut ()>` field. It exists to force `Id` to not implement `Send` or `Sync`, so that any reference to an `Id` remains confined to the thread it was created on. With `#![feature(negative_impls)]` you could use the much clearer solution of `impl !Send/!Sync for Id { }`, but this is unstable, so instead we simply add a dummy field which is not `Send` or `Sync` (because raw pointers are not Send/Sync and `PhantomData` shares the `Send`/`Sync` status of its argument.)

See also: [`PhantomData` in the Rust nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html), [`Send` and `Sync` in the Rust nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html)

If you do need to access `Parent` or `Child` from multiple threads, things become a little more complicated. We will need to store the next ID in a global atomic integer variable, but the problem is that there is no such thing as an 'atomic checked add,' so we cannot detect ID wrapping as simply as in the single-threaded case. The code will look something like this:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Id(u64);

impl Id {
   pub fn new() -> Id {
       static NEXT_ID: AtomicU64 = AtomicU64::new(0);
       let id = todo!(); // what goes here?
       Id(id)
   }
}
```

You haven't indicated whether you are relying on the `is_child` check to ensure memory safety or just logical correctness. If it's just the latter, you can get away with reserving `u64::MAX` to represent "we're out of IDs" and implement `Id::new` this way:

```
pub fn new() -> Id {
   static NEXT_ID: AtomicU64 = AtomicU64::new(0);
   let id = NEXT_ID.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
   if id == u64::MAX { panic!("Ran out of IDs!"); }
   Id(id)
}
```

Since panics are recoverable in Rust (and also run destructors), and the above only detects overflow *after* `NEXT_PARENT` has been incremented, in this case it is possible for two equal `Id`s to be created during or after a panic. If this could violate memory safety, you have two choices: either change the panic to `std::process::abort`, or use a compare-and-swap loop to check for overflow and avoid actually incrementing the counter, like this:

```
pub fn new() -> Id {
   static NEXT_ID: AtomicU64 = AtomicU64::new(0);
   let id = loop {
       let id = NEXT_ID.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
       if id == u64::MAX { panic!("Ran out of IDs!");
       if let Ok(_) = NEXT_ID.compare_exchange(id, id + 1, Ordering::Relaxed, Ordering::Relaxed) {
           break id
       }
       // another thread changed NEXT_ID after we checked for overflow, try again
   };
   Id(id)
}
```

Obviously, this loop may introduce a small performance penalty. Finally, keep in mind that `AtomicU64` is widely, but not universally, available. If portability is a concern, please refer to the [`std::sync::atomic` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html) and consider using `AtomicUsize` instead (though this could significantly increase the chance of hitting the overflow panic on 32-bit platforms).